# Early return, unless return value is nil

Tags: ruby

I have a lot of code that looks like this:

```
value = TopicLinkClick.create_from(new_params)
return value unless value.nil?

# do something else
```

I find this code is not so good because creating a temporary variable is troublesome and disruptive of my workflow, and it takes time to read and understand a large block of code that is meaningless.

Is there a better way for me to do this?

Comment: There's a giant `# do something else` placeholder — could you fill that in? Otherwise, this is a purely generic question, which would be off-topic for Code Review.

Comment: @200_success thanks for your comment. It may seem that huge part should be the one, but I only interest in two lines above, since it appears a lot in my code. And naming that meaningless variable name seem to my problem, and if I can resolve these 2 lines, it will help me a lot in my workflow.

Comment: It's always better to express the final value as an expression.
It's better to strive for 
`value || something_else`    (this whole expression yields a  value)

rather than early returns.

Answer (score 11):

> Naming temporary variable is troublesome because [...] sometimes it costs time to read and understand a large block of code meanwhile it doesn't give any meaning.

Well, then give it some meaning. The name `value` doesn't describe much of anything. Instead, you could do something like

```
def some_method
  new_click = TopicLinkClick.create_from(new_params)
  return new_click unless new_click.nil?
  # do something else
end
```

You *can* shorten it a bit, but I wouldn't recommend it, as it's not quite as clear in my opinion

```
def some_method
  return new_click if new_click = TopicLinkClick.create_from(new_params)
  # do something else
end
```

Your other options are of course to not return early, but use a good old conditional instead

```
def some_method
  new_click = TopicLinkClick.create_from(new_params)
  unless new_click
    # do something else
  end
end
```

Alternatively, if you've got your code factored really nicely into methods, you can do

```
def some_method
  TopicLinkClick.create_from(new_params) || some_other_method(...)
end
```

Or, if you need a bit more logic, you can use a `begin..end` block, but again it's not as nice in my opinion.

```
def some_method
  TopicLinkClick.create_from(new_params) || begin
    # do something else
  end
end
```

---

Overall, though, **your current approach is fine**. Just use more descriptive names.

If you have a method that's simply a shortcut for calling either method A *or* method B, then I'd recommend using the `method_a || method_b` trick. Otherwise, like @schism, I'd recommend against doing too much on one line (as in code blocks 2 and 5)

Answer (score 5):

Personally I don't think having one extra line per early return is much clutter. It doesn't seem like it'd take long to understand either.

That said, if you really wanted to, you could reduce it to one line. You'll still have to assign a variable though.

```
if !(value = TopicLinkClick.create_from(new_params)).nil? then return value
```